# Why typescript compile option --out is BAD?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I have already read this documentation : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

But i still dot not understand why using --out is always a wrong choice ?
I don't understand why using _reference.ts is a bad choice too ?

In my case, i'm using typescript with angularJs. So Dependency between entity (controller, service, ...) is manage by angularjs DI, so i don't need to use AMD or CommonJS syntaxe. I'm juste using typescript Module as namespace for angular Module. I got file name _all.ts (equivalent _reference.ts) wich contains reference to all my typescript files. Actually i'm using the following cmd to compile my project :

`".\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe" --target ES5 --out  "$(ProjectDir)\appNV.js" "$(ProjectDir)\_all.ts`

If my _all.ts is not supported by tsconfig.json, does that mean that i will have too re-reference all my files in 'files' section of my tsconfig.json ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that opinion should come with caveats. If you are writing a genuinely large-scale application, you definitely don't want to try and jam it into a single file.

For smaller applications, it is possible to manage a single-file deployment. In some cases, you may opt to do this because you want to reduce the number of HTTP requests.

My personal view is that using module loaders as standard is a good starting point. If you want a single file, you could achieve this using a tool such as the RequireJS optimizer, which will walk all of the module imports and draw it all into a single file. Working this way also allows you to switch between different module strategies easily (i.e. you can make everyone happy whether they want a single file, AMD modules or CommonJS modules - and very soon ECMAScript 6 modules).

The `--out` flag would be a last resort for me and out of the question for a really large program.

Comment: This is exactly how my TS builds are set up: gulp runs TS, then we use browserify or require to sort out modules later. Simple separation of responsibilities.